# How to filter an array of objects when object key contains specific values

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have an array of objects which contains orderId & productId. If order contains 2 specific productIds then we need to remove those objects, but only when both productIds present. Either one of the productId is not present then don't need to remove those objects.

- when the product Id's 454.110600 & 891.010000 match on the same order, delete both
- when the  product Id's 824.010000 & 890.010000 match on the same order, delete both

**Input:**

```
`[
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "454.110600"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "891.010000"   
  },
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "103.110603" 
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,
    "productId": "890.010000"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,
    "productId": "824.010000"   
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,  
    "productId": "123.110601"  
  },
{
    "orderId": 3,  
    "productId": "454.110600"  
  }]`
```

**Expected Output:**

```
`  [  
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "103.110603" 
  },  
  {
    "orderId": 2,  
    "productId": "123.110601"  
  },
{
    "orderId": 3,  
    "productId": "454.110600"  
  }]
`
```

I tried below dataweave, but not giving expected output

`%dw 2.0 var product = [ {"productId" : "454.110600"}, {"productId" : "891.010000"}, {"productId" : "824.010000"}, {"productId" : "892.010000"} ]`

`output application/json`

`---`

`((payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item."orderId")) pluck ((value, key, index) -> value)) map (items) ->  items filter (not (product contains {"productId": $."productId"}))`

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: Did you mean any two pairs from the product list have to be removed?

Comment: Hi @Nagesh, interested to learn why a simpler DW(that gives the expected output) as below, won't suffice your use-case:
(payload orderBy ((item, index) -> item.productId)) distinctBy ((item, index) -> item.orderId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the logic is correct but I understood it as remove the products from the order if the there are more than two products found in a list of products that needs to be removed. You can try below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var productIdsToRemove = ["454.110600", "891.010000", "824.010000", "890.010000"]

var groupedData = payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.orderId)

fun filterData(orderId) = do {
    var commonItems = groupedData[orderId].productId filter (productIdsToRemove contains $)
    ---
    if (sizeOf(commonItems) >= 2) groupedData[orderId] filter !(productIdsToRemove contains $.productId)
    else groupedData[orderId]
}
---
keysOf(groupedData) flatMap ((item, index) -> filterData(item))
```

This results to:

```
[
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "103.110603"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,
    "productId": "123.110601"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 3,
    "productId": "454.110600"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this script, I am using the filter function to exclude the orders that match the product IDs to remove. Additionally, I am checking if an order has only one occurrence in the payload to ensure that I don't remove orders when only one of the product IDs is present.

Please give it a try, and let me know if it produces the expected output.

DW Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var productIdsToRemove = ["454.110600", "891.010000", "824.010000", "890.010000"]

var filteredOrders = payload filter ((order) ->
  !(productIdsToRemove contains order.productId) or
  (sizeOf(payload filter (o) -> o.orderId == order.orderId) == 1))

---
filteredOrders
```

Comment: @ Harsha Shivamurthy - Thanks for quick response. I have tested the dataweave with below input and not getting expected output.
[
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "454.110600"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "103.110603" 
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,
    "productId": "890.010000"
  },  
  {
    "orderId": 2,  
    "productId": "123.110601"  
  },
   {
    "orderId": 3,  
    "productId": "125.110606"  
  }]
--- this input only contains one of the excluded productId's and not returning them in the output

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to remove pairs of productIds from each order if both are present in the same order.

My solution is a little verbose due to not having a better way to deal with pairs in DataWeave. I first group by orderId so I have each order in a key. Then for each order I filter products if a product is in one of the pairs and the other is also present in the same order. I need to duplicate the logic for the first element of the pair and then for the second. I create an object to find the other member of the pair more easily. After I filtered the elements I use pluck to create back an array (remember I used groupBy()) but it is nested, so I apply flatten() to get the expected result.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays

var productIdsToRemove = [["454.110600", "891.010000"], ["824.010000", "890.010000"]] 

fun mapPairs(pair)= { (pair[0]): pair[1], (pair[1]): pair[0]}

fun prodIdsExcluded(orders, order, pairs)=
    !(
        (pairs some (order.productId == $[0]) and (orders.*productId contains mapPairs($)[$[0]]))
    or
        (pairs some ( (order.productId == $[1]) and (orders.*productId contains mapPairs($)[$[1]])))
    )


fun removePairs(orders, pairs)=
 flatten(
    payload
    groupBy ($.orderId)
    mapObject ((value, key) -> 
        (key): value  filter ( prodIdsExcluded(value, $,productIdsToRemove))
    )
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> value)
 )    
---
removePairs(payload, productIdsToRemove)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "productId": "103.110603"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,
    "productId": "123.110601"
  },
  {
    "orderId": 3,
    "productId": "454.110600"
  }
]
```